# templateUrl paths broken when running Karma Unit Tests with Angular

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

Given the following structure.

```
root
---app
-----components
```

all of the directive templates use 'components/somemodule/some-template.html'

My node server typically runs the app from /app using express.static. Everything works fine.

PROBLEM: When running Karma Unit tests from the ROOT using grunt and trying to place a directive..
404 not found : 'components/somemodule/some-template.html'

Obviously because the references should be: `'app/components/somemodule/some-template.html'`

I cannot change this in my directive templates. Is there a way to tell Karma to find the right paths or have Karma run at the app level so it can resolve the paths?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was to have your templates loaded as JS into the browser that karma is running. There are any number of ways in which that can be done.

A preprocessor like [ng-html2js](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor) is something that can do that for you, by converting all of the templates to js for testing only. It also includes a number of path configuration options so that you shouldn't have to modify the path in your code.

Otherwise, a tool like [ng-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates) does the same thing but for use in your production code, again with the ability to adjust paths so that you aren't tied down to a relative folder structure.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to be working. Can you provide and example on how? It appears that when I drop a directive in, it's not referencing it by the template cache. It's referencing based on the added js dependencies physically.

Comment: What did you try and what isn't working? You might consider starting a new question with specifics on what you are doing that isn't working the way you want.